# React - map a list in state does not properly affect the UI

Tags: reactjs

I have a list in the state of the parent component:

```
this.state = {
    productsForm: [],
}
```

and I perform a map on the list and call a child component:

```
    renderProducts() {
    const result = this.state.productsForm.map((value, index) => (
      <ProductForm
        index={index}
        onChange={(name, form, strength) => {
          const productsForm = this.state.productsForm;
          productsForm[index] = { name, form, strength };
          this.setState({ productsForm });
        }}
        onRemove={(id) => {
          const filtered = this.state.productsForm.filter((_, i) => i !== id);
          this.setState({ productsForm: filtered });
        }}
      />
    ));
    return result;
   }
```

In the child component I have a remove button which returns the "id" of itself to the parent:

```
<FloatingActionButton
onClick={() => { onRemove(this.state.id); }}
>
```

It works and remove the child from the parent component, but in the UI, (I mean the html page in the browser) there is some problem. when ever I remove a child with a lower index, although it will be removed from the state, it remains in the UI!

I think there is a problem in the "index" or something like that in my code. Do you have any recommendation for me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `key` attribute to each `ProductForm` component. This way, React knows which components have been changed.

```
<ProductForm key={index} ... />
```

It's even better if you use the `product`'s  id as `key` instead of the index.

Answer (score 1):

Is `index` the `key` property in your `ProductForm`? If not, you need to add a key property. If yes, it's wrong to use `index` as the unique prop in either case. Look at this:

You have three elements in the array

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

React identifies them through the `key` prop. Now if you remove for example the key with `1` from your array it will be removed from your array, but it will remain in the UI `render` method. Because your array looks like this now

```
[0,1,2]
```

The key prop with `1` is still there. In the end this means you need to supply unique identities for example:

```
key={index + somethingUnique} // worst case you can generate random numbers
```